# Switch between StackNavigators?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, stack-navigator

I have base StackNavigator. and Inside Tabnavigator. inside Tabnavigator there is another stack navigator. now how to jump navigate to base StackNavigator ?

Comment: is `this.props.navigation.navigate` not working?

Comment: @AseemUpadhyay how can this work? it's work within same StackNAvigator

Comment: Giving some example code from your app here would help others help you. Also, is `this.props.navigation.navigate('baseStackNavigatorKey');` not working? (Here `baseStackNavigatorKey` is the key with which your base `StackNavigator` is defined in the router.